# XMPP chat in GWT Applications

Tags: java, gwt, xmpp, atmosphere

I am looking of something of this kind.
My application uses Google OAuth to login. Now, I want to integrate XMPP chat in my application.
When I am logged into my application through, using this chat, I shall be able to chat with people on like GTalk etc through the chat in my application.
That is I shall be able to chat with user in the application plus i can invite users outside the application using XMPP chat like GTalk.

At single time using group chat, I should be able to chat with users in my application and also with external users.

Any suggestions/ideas on "using what" and "how" can this be accomplished, will be highly appreciated

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searches and tryouts - It seems that Google does not have their own bosh endpoint which would proxy request to google xmpp server. So, somehow ProxyServlet isn't working for me to connect to google server.

But now I am able to connect to google server using JabberHTTPBind. I used the emite-0.4.7-proxies.jar, which has JabberHTTPBind servlet bundled. In web.xml, added the below servlet mapping

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jabber HTTP Binding Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jabber.JabberHTTPBind.JHBServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jabber HTTP Binding Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/http-bind/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This worked for me. And now I am able to connect to google server using Emite.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look on this project: https://github.com/EmiteGWT/emite

The hard part (the protocol - XMPP) is already there. All you need is to build an UI for it in your project and to handle authorization stuff.

Comment: How can I connect to Google Talk server using emite, to start a chat session with any valid gtalk user (abc@gmail.com), in my gwt application.